# C# script causing Unity Editor crash

Tags: c#, crash, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have what may be a very simple, or a very complex problem in my unity script.  Simply put, when attempting to use the .Add or .Insert methods on the open list in the method shown below, the Unity editor ceases responding to any input and hangs until forcibly closed in the task manager.

The method in question:

```
    private void addToOpen(location l){ //causes editor crash
        int fScore = l.getF (); //f score of the location to add
        int count = open.Count; //number of values in the list
        int index = 0; //index to insert the location

        Debug.Log ("count " + count);
        while (index < count) {
            if(fScore >= open[index].getF()){
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }

        open.Insert(index, temp);
    }
```

The code is attempting the implement an A* pathfinding algorithm.
I'm attempting to translate the code from the web page below into C#.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4970/how-to-implement-a-pathfinding-with-cocos2d-tutorial

A larger portion of my script is below to provide context:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic; //for lists
    using System; //for broad use of "Exception"

    public class MouseBasedMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject map; //Holds the map object
private MapDataA mapdataa; //stores reference to data script
public Camera mainCamera;
void Awake(){
    mapdataa = map.GetComponent<MapDataA> (); //Links variable with component
}

//object for storing tile locations
public class location{
    public int xCoor;
    public int yCoor;
    //methods rarely interact with f as it is usually ignored, I tried to keep it isolated from extra interactions and assignments
    public int f;
    location parent; //location the object came from in A* algorithm
    public int g;
    public int h;

    public location(){
        xCoor = 0;
        yCoor = 0;
    }

    public location(int x, int y){
        xCoor = x;
        yCoor = y;
    }

    public location(location l){
        //constructor creates a copy of the location but does not copy the F value
        xCoor = l.getX ();
        yCoor = l.getY ();
    }

    public location(int x, int y, location a, location b){ //constructor for a*
        //x is x coordinate
        //y is y coordinate
        //a is starting position in algorithm ("from" tile)
        //b is target position in algorithm ("to" tile)

        xCoor = x;
        yCoor = y; 

        //g , h , f
        //g = getD(a, new location (x,y));
        //h = getD(new location(x,y), b);
        //f = getD(a, new location (x,y)) + getD(new location(x,y), b);
        //--- seems I can not nest constructors, going to simply do the same job by not using the getD method and using the method's logic + code instead.

        //private int getD(location a, location b){ //used for calculating g and h
            //if G,
            //a is the start point
            //b is the current square

            //if H, 
            //a is the current square
            //b is the endpoint

        //  int total = Math.Abs (a.getY () - b.getY ()) + Math.Abs (a.getX () - b.getX ());
        //  return total;
        //}

        g = Math.Abs (a.getY () - y) + Math.Abs (a.getX () - x);
        h = Math.Abs (y - b.getY ()) + Math.Abs (x - b.getX ());
        f = (Math.Abs (a.getY () - y) + Math.Abs (a.getX () - x)) + (Math.Abs (y - b.getY ()) + Math.Abs (x - b.getX ()));


    }

    public void setX(int x){
        xCoor = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y){
        yCoor = y;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return xCoor;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return yCoor;
    }

    public void setParent(location p){
        parent = p;
    }

    public location getParent(){
        return parent;
    }

    public void setF(int i){
        f = i;
    }

    public int getF(){
        return f;
    }

    public void setG(int gset){
        g = gset;
    }

    public int getG(){
        return g;
    }

    public void setH(int hset){
        h = hset;
    }

    public int getH(){
        return h;
    }

    public bool compareTo(location c){
        if ((c.getX () == this.getX ()) && (c.getY () == this.getY ())){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string toString(){
        string str = "x: " + xCoor + " y: " + yCoor;
        return str;
    }
}

List<location> open = new List<location> (); //A* open list
List<location> closed = new List<location> (); //A* closed list
//method for the A* pathfinding algorithm's implementation in player movement
//Helped greatly in writing this section:
//http://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding
//http://www.raywenderlich.com/4970/how-to-implement-a-pathfinding-with-cocos2d-tutorial
public void aStar(location a, location b){
    //a is starting position
    //b is ending position

    //checks to see if the destination is the same as the current position
    if (a.compareTo (b) == true) {
        Debug.Log ("Already There");
        return;
    }

    //Checks to see if the id of the destination tile is 1, and thus innacessable
    Debug.Log (mapdataa.mapData.GetLength (0));
    Debug.Log (mapdataa.mapData.GetLength (1));
    Debug.Log (b.getY ());
    Debug.Log (b.getX ());
    if (mapdataa.mapData[b.getY(), b.getX ()].getId () == 1){
        Debug.Log ("Destination tile is inaccessable");
        return;
    }

    //checks to see if the tile is highlighted (aka in range)
    GameObject[] inRange = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("moveTransparent");
    bool found = false;
    foreach (GameObject trans in inRange) {
        if (trans.transform.position.x == b.getX () && trans.transform.position.y == b.getY ()){
            //tile is within range
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found == false) { //This section has worked in testing.
        //tile was never found to be within range
        Debug.Log ("Tile not in range/Tile not highlighted");
        return;
    }

    //begin A* actual algorithm implementation here
    bool pathFound = false;
    open.Add(new location ((int)transform.position.x, (int)transform.position.y, a, b)); //adds initial location of playable to open list 

    //testing
    Debug.Log ("open[0]: " + open[0].toString ());
    Debug.Log (open.Count);
    //end testing

    //above was previously an addToOpen method call, but I changed it to add, it SHOULD not affect logic, and may fix bugs
    location current = new location ();
    location temp = new location ();

    //Something in here (main algorithmic loop) is causing the crash
    do{
        //Get the lowest F score step
        //Because the list is ordered, the first step always has the lowest F score
        current = open[0];

        //add the current step to the closed list
        closed.Add (current);

        //remove the current step from the open list
        open.RemoveAt (0);

        //if current is the desired tile coordinate, the algorithm is complete
        if(current.compareTo (b)){
            pathFound = true;
            temp = current;
            Debug.Log ("Path Found");
            //LOOK INTO THIS! PARENT CHILD STRUCTURE NEEDS TO BE CONSIDERED
            do{
                Debug.Log (temp);
                temp = temp.getParent();
            }while(temp != null);
            break;
        }

        //get the adjacent tiles to the current step
        location[] adjSteps = getAdjacent (current,a,b);

        foreach (location loc in adjSteps){
            //check if the step isn't already in the closed set
            if (closed.Contains (loc)){
                continue; //effectively ignores it
            }

            //check if the step is already in the open list
            //NOTE: the line here in the source material is iffy, there might be functionality that I am not implementing
            if (open.Contains (loc) == false){
                //aka, not in the open list

                //set current step as the parent
                loc.setParent (current);                                                     //3

                //G score is parent g score + 1 (cost to move from parent to it)
                loc.setG (current.getG () + 1);                                              //4

                //compute H score
                loc.setH (getD (loc, b));                                                    //5

                //adding it to the open list
                addToOpen(loc);

            }else{
                //aka, already in the open list
                int index = open.IndexOf (loc); 
                //loc = open[index];

                //check to see if the G score is equal to the parent g score + cost to move(1)
                if(current.getG () + 1 < open[index].getG ()){
                    //The G score is equal to the parent G score + the cost to move to it
                    open[index].setG (current.getG () + 1);

                    //because the G score changed, f may change too
                    //so to keep the open list ordered, we have to remove and reinsert it

                    location locB = new location(open[index]); //added to circumvent bug

                    //remove from the list
                    open.RemoveAt (index);

                    //reinsert it
                    addToOpen (locB); //replaced loc with locB to circumvent bug
                }
            }

        }

    }while(open.Count > 0);

    if (!pathFound) { //no path found
        Debug.Log ("The algorithm failed to discover a path");
    }

}


    private void addToOpen(location l){ //causes editor crash
        int fScore = l.getF (); //f score of the location to add
        int count = open.Count; //number of values in the list
        int index = 0; //index to insert the location

        Debug.Log ("count " + count);
        while (index < count) {
            if(fScore >= open[index].getF()){
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }

        open.Insert(index, temp);
    }

//majorly reworked to prohibit returning null values to avoid editor crash while fixing bugs
private location[] getAdjacent(location l, location a, location b){
    location[] adjacents = new location[4];
    GameObject[] inRange = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("moveTransparent");
    bool found = false;
    int counter = 0;

    //up 
    location up = new location (l.getX (), l.getY () + 1,a ,b);
    foreach (GameObject trans in inRange) {
        if (trans.transform.position.x == up.getX () && trans.transform.position.y == up.getY ()){
            //tile is within range
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if ((found == true) && (mapdataa.mapData [up.getY (), up.getX ()].getId () == 0)) { //if tile is within range and is acessable
        adjacents [counter] = up; //add it to the list
        counter++;
    }
    found = false; //reset found variable

    //down
    location down = new location (l.getX (), l.getY () -1,a,b);
    foreach (GameObject trans in inRange) {
        if (trans.transform.position.x == down.getX () && trans.transform.position.y == down.getY ()){
            //tile is within range
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if ((found == true) && (mapdataa.mapData [down.getY (), down.getX ()].getId () == 0)) { //if tile is within range and is acessable
        adjacents [counter] = down; //add it to the list
        counter++;
    }
    found = false; //reset found variable

    //left
    location left = new location (l.getX () -1, l.getY (),a,b);
    foreach (GameObject trans in inRange) {
        if (trans.transform.position.x == left.getX () && trans.transform.position.y == left.getY ()){
            //tile is within range
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if ((found == true) && (mapdataa.mapData [left.getY (), left.getX ()].getId () == 0)) { //if tile is within range and is acessable
        adjacents [counter] = left; //add it to the list
        counter++;
    }
    found = false; //reset found variable

    //right
    location right = new location (l.getX () +1, l.getY (),a,b);
    foreach (GameObject trans in inRange) {
        if (trans.transform.position.x == right.getX () && trans.transform.position.y == right.getY ()){
            //tile is within range
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if ((found == true) && (mapdataa.mapData [right.getY (), right.getX ()].getId () == 0)) { //if tile is within range and is acessable
        adjacents [counter] = right; //add it to the list
        counter++;
    }
    found = false; //reset found variable

    if (counter < 4) { //if statement is logically useless, but for the sake of trying to get to work, I'm leaving it as is.  Once it runs, try removing the if statement and test again.
        adjacents = retract (adjacents, 4-counter);
    }

    return adjacents;
}

private int getD(location a, location b){ //used for calculating g and h
    //implements the "Manhatten method" of determining total vertical and horizontal distance on a grid

    //if G,
    //a is the start point
    //b is the current square

    //if H, 
    //a is the current square
    //b is the endpoint

    int total = Math.Abs (a.getY () - b.getY ()) + Math.Abs (a.getX () - b.getX ());
    return total;
}

bool ran = false;
public void Update(){
    if (ran == false) {
        highlight ();
        ran = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) { //if left click
        Debug.Log ("Begin Update method A* implementation testing");
        aStar (new location((int)transform.position.x,(int)transform.position.y),new location((int)((((mainCamera.transform.position.x * 64) - (.5 * Screen.width)) + Input.mousePosition.x) / 64),(int)((((mainCamera.transform.position.y * 64) - (.5 * Screen.height)) + Input.mousePosition.y) / 64)));
        Debug.Log ("End Update method A* implementation testing");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please use unity3d tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really debug this because I don't have the full context, but here's my guess from looking at the source  code

```
//This line seems to cause the editor crash
open.Insert (index, l);
```

Let's take a look at the variables used here:

- `open`: The list which stores elements (count **could** be zero)
- `index`: An index, starting at 1 (and staying at one **if** open.Count==0)

Maybe you can already spot the problem: The list has 0 elements and you are trying to insert an element at position 1. C# (or the CLR, rather) doesn't like this too much and just throws an exeption (at least in Visual Studio).

The crashing part is interesting. Since you are using Unity I'll assume you're using MonoDevelop as your editor. Does the editor crash at every exception? (try `int a=1/0` or something similar to test that). If it doesn't, It is likely you found a bug in MonoDevelop (in that case you should file a bug report). Of course it could also be that something else is causing the crash (for example an infinite loop in the algorithm).

Comment: Thank you.  My apologies, the index value was originally set to 0 but I changed it to test what would happen and forgot to change it back.  No exception is thrown in the case of an index value of 0 and I have found through further testing that any changes to the method that do not cause an exception but allow the algorithm to continue cause a freeze of the unity editor (but not monodevelop).  For this reason I believe there is an infinite loop in the algorithm, which I will attempt to fix.  The larger algorithm (admittedly somewhat dirty looking) should be included in the second code box.

Answer (score -1):

First, `open.InsertRange(index, temp)` is just wrong. Change it back to `open.Insert(index, l)`.

Second, you're not updating the F score when you add the adjacent tiles. If it's a new tile, you set G and H but not F. If it's already in the open list you even comment "because the G score changed, f may change too" but you don't update F. And F will always change, because F = G + H.

Maybe go a step back and think about how the algorithm *should* work. Either use the [introduction](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding) to your tutorial or the article from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) with some pseudocode.

If it still gets stuck somewhere, add some Debug.Log() into your aStar loop, so that you can keep track what your algorithm is doing. A small world is suggested for testing or else you will get lost ;)